# Why does the ternary operator in JSP always return false?

Tags: java, string, jsp

See the code snippet below:

```
<p:column id="WorkedDay"
    headerText="#{EManagedController.fDate}"
    styleClass="#{EManagedController.fDate.substring(0,3) eq 
    'Sun' or 'Sat'? 'color:blue !important' : 'color:black !important'}">
```

`EManagedController.fDate` does get the value from the controller, which carries `Sun`, `Sat` as well.
But why is `substring(0,3)` always returning false?

And the java code :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(currentFortnightDate);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Constants.localeCosnt);
cal.setTime(date);
setFDate(df.format(cal.getTime()));
```

and headerText="#{EManagedController.fDate}, It does print the value as header as well , in "Mon 22" format in browser.

Comment: Try case insensitive comparison.

Comment: Well `EManagedController.fDate.substring(0,3) eq 
    'Sun' or 'Sat'`  won't give you what you expect, it should be `(EManagedController.fDate.substring(0,3) eq 
    'Sun') or (EManagedController.fDate.substring(0,3) eq 'Sat')`, you should test each `String` separately.

Comment: @chsdk I have tried this approach as well, but not helping to fix the issue.

Comment: @Vikash Please post your Java code as well.

Comment: for debugging, try printing the value of EManagedController.fDate.substring(0,3)... EManagedController.fDate.substring(0,3) eq 
    'Sun'...

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd");  
Date date = sdf.parse(currentFortnightDate);  
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Constants.localeCosnt);  
cal.setTime(date);  
setFDate(df.format(cal.getTime()));`    @chsdk

Comment: @chsdk , headerText="#{EManagedController.fDate}, It does print the value as header as well , in "Mon  22" format

Comment: @Vikash Please post it as an edit to your question.

Comment: yes.. did it @chsdk

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your valuable answers.

It did work with below code :

```
<p:column id="WorkedDay"
    headerText="#{EManagedController.fDate}"
    style="background-color:#{EManagedController.fDate.substring(0,3)== 'Sat' or
    EManagedController.fDate.substring(0,3)== 'Sun'?  
    '#e6f0ff !important' : 'none !important'}">
```